# ContentResolver getCurrentSyncs(): SyncInfo account name is censored

Tags: android, account, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter

When I call **ContentResolver.getCurrentSyncs()** and print the account name of the SyncInfo object, I get stars (*****) instead of chars.

Is it only censored on the log, or is the string itself unreadable?
Any idea how I can specifically compare it? (equals)

```
String original = "myName";    

for (SyncInfo info : ContentResolver.getCurrentSyncs()) {
        Log.i(info.account.name); // prints ******

        boolean result = original.equals(info.account.name); // always false?
}
```

permissions granted:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
```

on Android M

**EDIT:**
Accessing the account names directly from AccountManager are readable. (getAccounts())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

Did not find any documentation but in the [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/sources/android-25/android/content/SyncInfo.java) of **SyncInfo.java** at line 32:

```
/**
 * Used when the caller receiving this object doesn't have permission to access the accounts
 * on device.
 * @See Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
 */
private static final Account REDACTED_ACCOUNT = new Account("*****", "*****");
```

I double checked the permission, but did not find something wrong, so I disconnected the phone, got icetea and watched netflix. That fixed the issue.

Edit: I changed the account type definition at one point, but that does not explain why getCurrentSyncs() got censored and getAccounts() wasn't.

Edit2: Got the issue on another phone: After disabling and re-enabling the CONTACTS permission my app required, GET_ACCOUNTS was granted truly and the issue disappeared.

Comment: Thanks for the CONTACTS permission tip, if fixed the issue. Strange thing is - I do not read device contacts at all...